# Why doesn't it work to put minimum 100 on stepper class in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, argumentexception

I don't understand why I got this message.
I asked someone, he said that it doesn't like 100,
but I still wonder why.

[image: I got this message....]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason can be found in the [documents](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Stepper/):

> Minimum - An integer or decimal literal. If this value is nonnegative,
>   it must appear lexically below Maximum, so that validation can
>   succeed.

Which means you must declare the stepper as such:

```
stepper = new Stepper {
   Maximum = 200, //note that maximum is declared first.
   Minimum = 100,
   Value = 100,       
   Increment = 10
};
```